# How to change Xcode 8.2.1 launch screen and main.storyboard to show iPhone 6 device?

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode8

New to Xcode. In the Single View App in Main.storyboard and Launchscreen.storyboard on the bottom under "view as" it gives me option between 2 iPad devices, iPhone 7 Plus, 7, SE and 4s. How do I get iPhone 6 to be included for both storyboards? I want to launch iPhone 6 simulator because iPhone plus, 7 and SE simulators are larger than my screens with a scroll yet the 4s is not available as simulator. iPhone 6 fits in my screen. How do I add iPhone 6 in the "view as" feature? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For **Xcode before 8.0:**

You can set that from attribute inspector on right side, like below.

Select any **viewController** and then in **attributes inspector** tab.

[image]

For **Xcode 8.0 and Above:**

The above option is removed. Now we have to select a pre-defined devices from **"View as"** option in left-bottom most corner. Other way is to

> select view controller--> Size inspector--> change to freedom -->
>   Specifying width and height of iPhone 6

Comment: When I click on storyboard, in the size section I get options between Inferred, free form, page sheet, form sheet, detail, and master. I don't get any iPhone specific size preferences.

Comment: Not storyboard. Instead, click on individual view controller in storyboard and click on attribute inspector option.

Comment: I did click on the view controller, I just thought it was also called Storyboard, but now I know not so. Under attributes Inspector, Size, the options pop up as I mentioned above.

Comment: Your new edit, doesn't add the iPhone 6 device size in the "view as" section. I guess you can't add iPhone 6. Thanks for your help though.